# Toggle +/- in element on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `table` with expand and collapse already working, but I would like to add the `+` and `-` buttons to make the functionality more dynamic. Can anyone help me with that?

```js
$('tr.header').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function(i, v) {
    return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  });
});
```

```css
tr {
  display: none;
}

tr.header {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cdh4L23/

Comment: Thanks for editing Rory! I'm learning English and sometimes my syntax is a little confusing.

Comment: No problems at all with your English, all I really added was the snippet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can add a `span` element to the `.header` cell to contain the `+` or `-`. When the click occurs you can swap the characters over based on their current values.

Also note that you can use a CSS class to display the `tr` elements which makes the JS a little cleaner as you can use `toggleClass()` instead of a ternary in `css()`.

```js
$('tr.header').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .find('span').text((i, t) => t === '+' ? '-' : '+').end()
    .nextUntil('tr.header').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
tr { display: none; }
tr.show { display: table-row; }
tr.header { display: table-row; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header <span>+</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header <span>+</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```